# Spout Error from Apache Storm Trident and Kafka Integration

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-kafka, apache-storm, trident

I am using OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout to consume messages from Kafka. Below is the code. I have ignored `max spout pending` configuration as this is causing same kafka message to arrive in multiple batches.

```
TridentKafkaConfig tridentKafkaConfig = new TridentKafkaConfig(hosts,properties.getProperty("topic", "mytopic"));
tridentKafkaConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout(tridentKafkaConfig);
```

I am getting the following error once as the Kafka Spout starts, but runs smoothly afterwards.

> 2018-05-29 09:47:21.703 o.a.s.util
>   Thread-9-spout-myspout-Spout-executor[33 33] [ERROR] Async loop died!
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:522)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:487)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:74)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5043$fn__5056$fn__5109.invoke(executor.clj:861)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484)
>   [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.trident.KafkaTridentSpoutEmitter.seek(KafkaTridentSpoutEmitter.java:193)
>   ~[stormjar.jar:?]
>           at org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.trident.KafkaTridentSpoutEmitter.emitPartitionBatch(KafkaTridentSpoutEmitter.java:127)
>   ~[stormjar.jar:?]
>           at org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.trident.KafkaTridentSpoutEmitter.emitPartitionBatch(KafkaTridentSpoutEmitter.java:51)
>   ~[stormjar.jar:?]
>           at org.apache.storm.trident.spout.OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor$Emitter.emitBatch(OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor.java:141)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.trident.spout.TridentSpoutExecutor.execute(TridentSpoutExecutor.java:82)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.trident.topology.TridentBoltExecutor.execute(TridentBoltExecutor.java:383)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5043$tuple_action_fn__5045.invoke(executor.clj:739)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_task_receiver$fn__4964.invoke(executor.clj:468)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__4475.onEvent(disruptor.clj:41)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:509)
>   ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
>           ... 6 more

Any suggestions regarding this ?

Comment: Could you please post the whole stack trace? There's likely a "caused by" line below what you posted that'll tell you where the NPE is coming from.

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing I have updated the whole stack trace. Thanks

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing I guess my problem is closely related to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/wzdduOWul54

Comment: The code snippet you posted doesn't match the stack trace. The code snippet is using the storm-kafka Trident spout, while the stack trace appears to be using the storm-kafka-client Trident spout. Which are you using?

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing I am using Storm Kafka Client. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace indicates that you are hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-3046.

Comment: What would you suggest in order to fix this problem ?

Comment: Try out the fixed storm-kafka-client, the source is here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-3046?focusedCommentId=16494080&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16494080